# dateSignedTabs is not giving right date

Tags: docusignapi

i have created an envelope using rest api

endpoint :- {{baseUrl}}/envelopes

method :-post

body:

{

```
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document sent from Node SDK",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "<NAME>",
            "documentBase64": "base64DOC"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "<EMAIL@EMAIL>COM",
                "name": "<USERNAME>",
                "clientUserId": 1,
                "recipientId": 1,
                "tabs": {
                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "todaysDate",
                            "xPosition": "20",
                            "yPosition": "75",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"

}
```

envelope is created succesfully ,when i am opening the url of recipient view UI. A static value "10/3/2018" is filled in the dateSignedTabs. Why current date is not filled in the dateSignedTabs.
[image: resultant document]

Answer (score 0):

The date is populated the first time the recipient opens the envelope for signing.
Each tab (including date tab) is for a specific recipient.
When that specific recipient first clicks on the link (or if using embedded signing - opens the view) then the date is populated. It will not be updated again if you open it again and it's not updated for other recipients, only for the one for which this tab was set.

Hope this helps.